# Can I split the graph into pages into unequal parts?

Tags: delphi, teechart

For example, the graph consists of **300** points. The method `'Chart1.MaxPointsPerPage:=100'` splits the graph into **3** pages of **100** points. I want to split this graph into unequal parts, i.e.

**for example**:

> 1 page-0-50 points
>   2 page 51-150 points
>   3 page 151-200 points
>   4 pages 200-300 points

Comment: You can load needed portion of data "by hands" when page changes

Comment: That's right, I also thought to solve the issue in this way, thank you. As a result, I came to the conclusion that the standard means of splitting the chart into equal parts is sufficient.